# Move polygon with move_ip in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I can't get to move a polygon with the function move_ip() in pygame, the code works good if I draw a rectangle, but not with polygon. It doesn't respond when I press any arrow key.

I think I don't need **spaceship rectangle** because polygons are rects with pygame, but it seems not right, I don't know, i've got a mess.

This is my pygame code:

```
import sys, os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy as np

if sys.platform in ["win32","win64"]: os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"]='1'

width_screen = 600
height_screen = 480
screen_size = (width_screen, height_screen)
positionx_screen = 0
positiony_screen = 32
title_window = 'ASTEROIDS'

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

spaceship = pygame.Rect(200, 475, 120, 20)

def quit_screen(event):
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()


class Spaceship():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.colour = WHITE
        self.thickness = 0
        self.movex = 20

    def draw_nave(self):
        vertices = np.array([[screen_size[0]/2, screen_size[1] /2 - 30],[screen_size[0]/2 + 15, screen_size[1]/2],
                             [screen_size[0]/2-15, screen_size[1] / 2]])
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen_game, self.colour, vertices, self.thickness)


    def move_spaceship_right(self):
        spaceship.move_ip(self.movex, 0)


    def move_spaceship_left(self):
        spaceship.move_ip(- self.movex, 0)


def game():
    pygame.init()
    running = True
    global screen_game
    screen_game = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size,
                                          positionx_screen, positiony_screen)
    pygame.display.set_caption(title_window)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    my_spaceship = Spaceship(200, 475, 120, 20)

    screen_game.fill(BLACK)
    while running:
        screen_game.fill(BLACK)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            quit_screen(event)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    my_spaceship.move_spaceship_right()
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    my_spaceship.move_spaceship_left()


        my_spaceship.draw_nave()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        game()
    except:
        pygame.quit()
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your `Rect` is in no way related to the polygon you draw. You simply draw it at the same position every time.

Better create a `Surface` once, draw your polygon on that `Surface` once, and use `spaceship` as position when drawing that new `Surface`.

I recommend subclassing from `Sprite`, create that `Surface` in the `__init__` function, and save the `Rect` in `self.rect` instead of the `spaceship` variable.

Then either use the `draw` function of `Sprite` or put your `Sprite` into a `Group`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I don't understand why I must use Sprites when i don't have images. Thanks